# Fix indentation of if-else in VS2015

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, code-formatting

This is how VS2015 indents code (using "Format Document"):

```
void actual()
{
    int i = 0;
    if (i == 1)
        Text = "a";
    else
 if (i == 0)
        Text = "b";
    else
        Text = "c";
}
```

Is there a way to fix it to have corresponding `if` and `else` statements with the same indentation, and indented more than the previous indentation *without* adding brackets?

**EDIT**

I would expect it to be like in previous versions (VS 2010 and 2013):

```
void expected()
{
    int i = 0;
    if (i == 1)
        Text = "a";
    else
        if (i == 0)
            Text = "b";
        else
            Text = "c";
}
```

Comment: Yes, write `else if` properly on one line.

Comment: @Chris Besides the fact that that doesn't solve the problem (check and see) - I didn't ask how to format it in your "proper" style. To each his own.

Comment: I agree, to each his own. I've just never ever seen someone write it like that.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand how you want it. As the first example, the second or something else?

Comment: Maybe you should mock it up for us to see how you think it should look.  But @Chris is right, your `else if` probably should be on one line since it's part of that if branch.  Unless you meant for the second `if` to be indented more, in which case, the meaning of your if statement changes, and you are missing a couple of proper squiggly brackets.

Comment: @Gilles They were just two ways (with and without brackets) which VS formatted differently. I removed the first and edited the question now.

Comment: @LarsTech Edited. I hope it's clearer now.

Comment: Yes.  You have an `else if`.  What you need is `else {` and then a closing `}` after the `Text = "c";` line.

Comment: @LarsTech Thanks. But I was wondering if we can get the old behavior back somehow, so we won't need that. Perhaps it's gone for good...

Comment: Doing the formatting like that doesn't really match the logic of the statement. It'll also look really funny once you have, let's say, 4 else-if's in the same statement..!

Comment: @LarsTech Semantically same: depending on how we defined if-else statements in EBNF @ispiro's view is correct to. If isfollowed by an instruction or instruction block. That block can be one instruction, a set of instructions grouped by curly braces or a complex instruction. In this case that block is another full blown if-else statement block. I interpret his code as the VS 2010 and 2013 indented it and IMHO that's how the compiler interprets it too. The `if else` notation is beneficial when you use many if-else, basically almost a switch-case.

Comment: @Chris If you have 4 if-else then use a switch-case. Otherwise this absolutely makes sense logically. I just hope noone downvoted the OPs question just because they think that only `else if` exists.

Comment: @Chris You do realize that that's what it's translated to "under the hood", right? Chaining `if`s is just executing the second if-else as the else of the first. But let's not argue, as we both said - to each his own. And thanks for your input!

Comment: @CsabaToth Not all if's can easily be rewritten as a switch..! Besides, it was just an example to make a point..!

Comment: @inspiro Just having a hard time wrapping my head around the reason for formatting like that..! But you're right, no point in arguing. Didn't mean to come across as rude!

Comment: @Chris No problem.

Answer (score 1):

You have an `if` with 3 branches that you are trying to treat as a 2 branch `if` with another `if` inside it.  This doesn't seem to be a formatting problem, but rather a problem with the interpretation of how the branches work.

If you *really* want it as 2 separate `if`s then you would have to write it this way:

```
void expected()
{
    int i = 0;
    if (i == 1)
        Text = "a";
    else
    {
        if (i == 0)
            Text = "b";
        else
            Text = "c";
    }
}
```

Comment: I understand how they work. And yes, I do want it like in your code. But I would like to do that _without_ the brackets, as it was possible in previous versions of VS.

Comment: I'd actually consider formatting from the earlier version of Visual Studio to be a bug.  I've just gone through the C# formatting settings and don't see any way to restore the previous behavior.  There *may* be a plugin out there someplace that can format the code the way you want, but I don't know of any off-hand.

Comment: You don't "have to" write it this way. Semantically this is equal to an `else if` structure people are mentioning in the comments or the form what the OP wants.